# Multiple UICollectionView in the same ViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using custom `UICollectionView` layout for having different size of cells and I am not able to have a section in this.

Is it good idea to use multiple `UICollectionView`s in the same `UIViewController`? Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 7):

it's simple

for every UICollectionView Delegates

```
- (NSUInteger)maximumNumberOfColumnsForCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
heightForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath

- (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView`
```

write condition inside:

```
    if (collectionView == myCollectionView1)
    {
    // do this 
    }
    else if (collectionView == myCollectionView2)
    {
    // do this 
    }
```

lets say for example in

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if (collectionView == myCollectionView1)
    {
     return 12;
    }
    else if (collectionView == myCollectionView2)
    {
     return 7; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Tag Property for distinguish between multiple UICollectionView or UITableView in one View Controller.

```
firstCollectionView.tag = 1;
secondCollectionView.tag = 2;
and so on ...
```

Now, In delegate methods use if to check UICollectionView

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(collectionView.tag == 1)
  {
    //cell for first UICollectionView or CollectionView with tag equal to 1
  }
  else if(collection.tag == 2)
  {
    //cell for second UICollectionView or CollectionView with tag equal to 2
  }
}
```

Use same technique in other delegate methods.